# Cleanup ActiveRecord field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have model `Article` it has field `title` with some text that may contain some "magic" patterns. In some cases i need to process text in title and other cases i don't, but in last case i need to get string w/o that patterns.

For example i have title value like **"Something **very** interesting"** and when i call `@article.title` i need to get cleaned up string like **"Something very interesting"**, but when i call `@article.title_raw` i need get original string.

The problem also is that i have working application and i cannt do "revolution" but what way to go...

--
Excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: When you say there are "Magic Patterns" are these implemented directly or using some form of markup library like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_(markup_language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regexp

```
@article.title.gsub(/pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|.../, '')
```

IE

```
@article.title
#=> "Some _cool_ **text**"
@article.title.gsub(/**|_/, "")
#=> "Some cool text"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have defined methods on the Article model called "title_raw" and "title" and in those methods do the alterations needed to the value and return them in those functions. Something like this:

def title
  title.gsub(/**|_/, "")
end

def title_raw
  self.title
end